# Substring_index in Mysql should return blank string if delimeter not found

Tags: mysql

```
 E:g  

 Case 1: delimeter not exist 

 string = "abcdefg"

      mysql> select substring_index(string,'z',1) from table;
      output: abcdefg
      expected output : blank string ""

 Case 2: delimeter exist 

 string = "abczdefg"

       mysql> select substring_index(string,'z',1) from table;
       output: abc
       expected output : abc (same as substring returns)
```

I want this select query should return me blank string if 'z'(delimeter) is not exist
and if delimeter exist in string then whatever substring_index is regular functionality

what modification in Query i can do for my expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Substring_index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) does exactly what it should :)
For your task you can use [substring](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

```
set @str = "abcdef";
select substring(@str, 1, LOCATE('z', @str) - 1) from dual;
```

That will do exactly what you want

Comment: and what if i want  "def" (string after delimeter) in case 2

Comment: select substring(@str, LOCATE('z', @str) + if(LOCATE('z', @str) = 0, 0, 1)) from dual